# How to disable Primefaces fileUpload when reaching the limit of files in a multiple file fileUpload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I trying to disable the file upload (PrimeFaces JSF) when I add  5 files without uploading the files. Just when select 5 files.

```
<p:fileUpload
            styleClass="button-text-icon-left"
            label="Up"
            id="Up"
            mode="advanced"
            dragDropSupport="false"
            multiple="true"
            sizeLimit="10000000"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)^[^.]+$|\.(?!(exe)$)([^.]+$)/"
            fileLimit="5"
            fileLimitMessage="Exceeds the maximum of 5 files.  "
            invalidSizeMessage="The file exceeds 10 MB, please reduce the size. "
            previewWidth="30"
            widgetVar="upcomponent"
            invalidFileMessage="EXE files are not allowed.  " />
```

I tried to use onAdd method but it doesn't work in that version of primefaces or a used in that way.

```
<p:fileUpload mode="advanced" multiple="true" auto="true"
            listener="#{testView.handleFileUpload}" 
            onAdd="console.log(this);console.log(file);callback.call(this, file);"/>
```

Comment: You didn't mention your version of PrimeFaces?

Comment: i am using primeface 5.3